# <iframe> downloads pdf file instead of displaying

Tags: angular, pdf, iframe, display, content-disposition

This is my component.html

```
    <iframe [src]="frameSrc | safe"  class="frameSet" type="application/pdf"
     frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
     This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: 
     <a href="frameSrc | safe">Download PDF</a>
   </iframe>
```

When this component opens in my browser (**Chrome**), the pdf is downloaded instead of display. The `frameSrc` is coming from a parent component which I'm assigning as the `[src]`. I want to display the pdf instead of downloading. I did some research and found out the `Content-Disposition` is `attachment` in my browser default. How could I change this so this works on every browser?

Answer (score 1):

- I don't understand why there's brackets around an attribute: `[src]` If you don't already know: Don't do that.
- `<iframe>` doesn't have `type` as a valid attribute, but `type` does work for `<iframe>`'s sister tags `<object>` and `<embed>`.

The following Demo does not function on SO due to their restrictive sandbox. Go to this <s>**Plunker**</s> to see a functional Demo. Source PDF courtesy of **[PDFObject](https://pdfobject.com/static.html)**

---

<s>Plunker</s>
---
Demo
====

***It looks like Plunker no longer runs embeded content anymore, so if you want to review a functioning demo, simply copy and paste the entire code in any text editor (Notepad, Notepad++, etc.) and save as an HTML file (.html file extension).***

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    figure {
      display: table;
      border: 3px ridge grey;
      position: relative;
      width: 96vw;
      min-height: 250px;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0 auto 35px;
    }
    
    figcaption {
      border: 3px ridge grey;
      text-align: center;
      font: 900 20px/1.5 Verdana;
      padding: 0 0 8px 0;
      background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3);
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    iframe,
    object,
    embed {
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <figure>
    <figcaption>IFRAME</figcaption>
    <iframe src="https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=1" class="frameSet" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <figcaption>OBJECT</figcaption>
    <object data="https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=2" class="objectSet" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <figcaption>EMBED</figcaption>
    <embed src="https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=3" class="embedSet" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
  </figure>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: in my case my link doesn't work, i go your demo and replace my link PDF to yours and still doesn't work, please help me to fix my problem.

Comment: I cut and paste the url to the browser address bar, so it works with a PDF plugin, but I understand you need to be accessible to a greater range of users. What I believe is the problem is that the server it's on doesn't run on a secure protocol. Cut and paste the url in an address bar ***but before you open the URL***, add an `s` to `http:` => `https:`

Comment: tanks alot for your answer, i install a module to my application and fix the problem. this is my module: https://github.com/vadimdez/ng2-pdf-viewer

Comment: ng2-pdf-viewer is used to load local pdf not the one over https

Answer (score -3):

The thing is that i was rendering a pdf which was over https and all i was getting is CORS error all the time

I just added a meta tag in the index.html file as in the  section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

and in the page/module where i wanted to display it is as below:

```
  <object data="your_url_to_pdf" type="application/pdf">
     <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer? 
     url=your_url_to_pdf&embedded=true"
     frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen 
     allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
  </object>
```